# CMake is not compiling with Qt 4

Tags: c++, qt, cmake

I am trying to build AMAROK on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin). I have installed Qt 5 already, but I am getting the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message):
  Could NOT find Qt4: Found unsuitable version "4.8.2", but required is at
  least "4.8.3" (found /usr/bin/qmake)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:313 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1393 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:83 (find_package)
```

Comment: Do you have both Qt4 and Qt5 installed?

Comment: The message says ' Found unsuitable version "4.8.2", but required is at least "4.8.3"'. What is unclear about that?

Comment: @tsnorrri: I have installed Qt 5 only.

Comment: What should I do? Install a version of Qt between 4.8.3 and 4.8.6

Answer (score 7):

It clearly wants Qt 4:

> "Could NOT find Qt4"

And you have only Qt 5 installed:

"I have installed Qt 5 only"

So suggest you try:

```
apt search ^qt4
```

I'm on Mint 17.3, an Ubuntu derivative, and hence similar if not the same repositories and of the packages listed I have these installed:

```
qt4-designer         - graphical designer for Qt 4 applications
qt4-dev-tools        - Qt 4 development tools
qt4-linguist-tools   - Qt 4 Linguist tools
qt4-qmake            - Qt 4 qmake Makefile generator tool
```

And I can build Amarok just fine from the latest code at:

```
git://anongit.kde.org/amarok.git
```

without problem.